Google Places API: Unable to Retrieve More Than 5 Reviews
I'm using the Google Spreadsheet and Google Places API to fetch reviews for my business listing, but I'm encountering an issue where I can only retrieve 5 reviews, even though I know there are over 800 available. Here’s a summary of my setup and the issue:
  const apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY'; // Replace with your API key
  const placeId = 'MY_PLACE_ID'; // Your Place ID
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${placeId}&fields=name,reviews&key=${apiKey}`;

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Clear previous data but keep the header row
  sheet.getRange('A2:D').clearContent();
  
  let nextPageToken = '';
  let allReviews = [];
  let totalReviewsCount = 0;

  do {
    const requestUrl = nextPageToken ? `${url}&pagetoken=${nextPageToken}` : url;
    
    Logger.log('Requesting URL: ' + requestUrl);
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl);
    const json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    
    Logger.log('API Response: ' + JSON.stringify(json));

    if (json.result && json.result.reviews) {
      const reviews = json.result.reviews;
      totalReviewsCount += reviews.length;

      allReviews = allReviews.concat(reviews);
      nextPageToken = json.next_page_token || '';

      Logger.log('Retrieved ' + reviews.length + ' reviews. Total so far: ' + totalReviewsCount);
      Logger.log('Next Page Token: ' + nextPageToken);

      if (nextPageToken) {
        Utilities.sleep(3000); // Wait before fetching the next page
        Logger.log('Waiting for 3 seconds before the next request...');
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No more reviews or next_page_token not found.');
      nextPageToken = '';
    }
  } while (nextPageToken);

  // Populate the sheet with all reviews
  if (allReviews.length > 0) {
    allReviews.forEach((review, index) => {
      const row = index + 2; // Start from the second row (A2)
      const reviewDate = new Date(review.time * 1000);
      const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(reviewDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
      
      sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(review.author_name);  // Column A: Author Name
      sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(formattedDate);       // Column B: Review Date
      sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(review.rating);        // Column C: Rating
      sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(review.text);          // Column D: Review Text
    });
  } else {
    sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue("No reviews found.");
  }

  Logger.log('Total reviews fetched: ' + totalReviewsCount);
}

Logs: When I run the script, the logs show the following:
Info: Next Page Token: 
Info: Total reviews fetched: 5

The next_page_token is empty, indicating there are no additional reviews to fetch, which is not consistent with what I see on my Google My Business listing.
May I know what should I do?

This question is similar to: Get reviews from google map api. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
